# query to obtain final status as fail when any one of listed subject is failed

Tags: mysql, oracle, cassandra, hive, db2

Select count(course),course,dept,
Case 
When ****condition*** then 'passed' 
Else 'failed'
End as finalstatus
from college group by course,dept;

Here condition should check each subject of each student if any student fails atleast one subject then final status should be failed or if student passes all subjects then final status should be passed

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Are you having an error or an unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all columns in group by which are present in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `CASE` condition relies on columns different from `course` and `dept`, you may need to include your `CASE` expression in `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Select count(course)
       course,
       dept,
       Case When ****condition*** then 
            'passed'
        Else 
            'failed'
       End as finalstatus
from college
group by course,
         dept,
         Case When ****condition*** then 
              'passed'
          Else 
              'failed'
         End;
```